# Replace string with rule

Tags: php, string, replace

I have s string contain a string like   `%somestring1:somestring2%`.I want to replace these strings with another one,if it is in the format of `%---:-----%`

example,

```
  $str="test content %list:UnsubscriptionLink% some other %list:subscriptionLink% test";
```

I want to replace the existance with '#' will be

```
   $str="test content # some other # test";
```

How can be possible?

**NOTE**

I can't predict somestring1,somestring2.it is dynamic.

```
$str="test content %list:UnsubscriptionLink% some other test";
echo preg_replace('~(%.*%)~','#',$str); //Its working
```

But

```
$str="test content %list:UnsubscriptionLink% some other %list:UnsubscriptionLink% test";
echo preg_replace('~(%.*%)~','#',$str); //Its Not working
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/134225)**

Comment: What have you tried so far ? I see 2 possibilities there : Regex, or if you don't know them parsing the string, finding the index of first `%` and the one right after thet, and removing the part of the string in between those. Anyway be carefull that if your "test content" or "some other test" strings contain a `%`, the replace you're making could have side effects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP string replace?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7721314/), [how to replace the substrings in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8800010/), [PHP replace preceding substrings of some other substring](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22327199/), [Find a substring and replace it to a specified char](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7414453/), and many, many more.

Comment: I know it is possible with preg_replace,But i don't know how to write the expression

Comment: ... [Replace a substring that is between square brackets with php regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8005699/90527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this Using [**`preg_replace`**](https://www.php.net/preg_replace)

**FOR YOUR UPDATED QUESTION**

[**`Regex Explanation`**](http://regex101.com/r/xN6rH1)

```
<?php
$str="test content %list:UnsubscriptionLink% some other %list:UnsubscriptionLink% test";
echo preg_replace('~(%[^%]+%)~','#',$str);
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://eval.in/134226)</kbd>

**OUTPUT**:

```
test content # some other # test
```

Comment: At least one usefull answer :-)

Comment: Its working only the string contain 1 occurance,But not working in my updated example

Comment: @shijin It's Ok Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo Code Viper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/to8yi2)**</kbd>

#### Pattern [Check](http://tinyurl.com/pgc5rdq)

```
~%[^%]+%~
```

#### PHP

```
<?php   
    $str="test content %list:UnsubscriptionLink% some other %list:UnsubscriptionLink% test";
    echo preg_replace('~%[^%]+%~','#',$str);
?>
```

#### Result

```
test content # some other # test
```

Comment: Its working only the string contain 1 occurance,But not working in my updated example.Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry for showing your answer late now i update my answer for your requirement. its work fine.